# Node.js - child_process.exec and output redirection

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to write a file templating script using Node.js. I have a JSON file called `template.json` which stores template information. The idea behind my script is that, if I type something like:

```
tmpl.js java Joe
```

it will do the following:

1. Call `touch Joe.java`
2. Read `template.json` to get the template for Java files
3. Use its information to replace all the placeholders with `Joe`
4. Write the result to `Joe.java`
5. Execute `emacsclient Joe.java`

Now, I wrote this script as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node --harmony

var templates = require('./config/template.json'),
    args = process.argv;

if (args.length < 4) {
    console.log("Not enough arguments!");
} 
else {
    var type = args[2],
        name = args[3];
    if (type in templates) {
        var tmpl = templates[type],
            contents = make_output(tmpl["format"],name),
            file_name = name + tmpl["extension"],
            command = "touch " + file_name + " && echo -e '" + contents +
            "' &> " + file_name + " && emacsclient " + file_name;
        invoke(command);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No template for %s", type);
    }
}


//Helpers

//Invokes comm with args in the terminal, returns all output
//Does not play nice with command redirection
function invoke(comm) {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child = exec(comm,
             function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                         if (error !== null) {
                 console.log(stderr);
                 }
             });
}

//If template is a format string, processes it with x as the
//replacement. Otherwise, just evaluates.
//Limited to one replacement at most.
function make_output(template, x) {
    if(/.*\%s.*/i.test(template)) {
        var util = require('util');
        return util.format(template,x);
    }
    else {
        return template;
    }
}
```

Basically, the command it ends up building is something like:

```
touch Joe.java && echo -e `bunch of template stuffs` &> Joe.java && emacsclient Joe.java
```

Now, the problem I am getting is that the above command relies on output redirection, which my `invoke` command doesn't deal with very well - specifically, everything executes, but I get an empty file! Is there a way I can change either `invoke` or what I'm constructing to *be* invoked to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Node's `child_process.exec` starts `sh` but you are using features that are peculiar to `bash`. The `&>` is interpreted as `& >` in `sh` (two operators: a control operator and a redirection operator) and `echo -e` will use `sh`'s builtin implementation of `echo`, which does not understand `-e`.

It would probably be possible to work around the issues above but using the shell like you do is fragile. For instance if your template contains single quotes (`'`), these quotes may interfere with the single quotes you use in your command. A more robust way to do it would be to change the main part of your code to use `fs.writeFileSync` rather than using shell commands to write to your file:

```
var templates = require('./config/template.json'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    args = process.argv;

if (args.length < 4) {
    console.log("Not enough arguments!");
}
else {
    var type = args[2],
        name = args[3];
    if (type in templates) {
        var tmpl = templates[type],
            contents = make_output(tmpl["format"],name),
            file_name = name + tmpl["extension"],
            command = "emacsclient " + file_name;

        fs.writeFileSync(file_name, contents);

        invoke(command);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No template for %s", type);
    }
}
```

You'd also want to modify `make_output` to perform the transformations that `echo -e` would have done for you.